# how to render svg element of d3.js using react.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I'm trying to render graph using react.js. In which I'm trying to use simple ReactDOM.render() method on html page. when I'm appending this graph content to the body it will work for me well but I want to render this using react.js.

**program-code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<!--react js url here -->
</head>
<body>
<script>
var csv_data = "date,bucket,count\n19:37:1 164,30000,12\n19:37:1 283,30000,8\n19:37:1 349,80000,2\n19:37:1 421,30000,16\n19:37:1 599,30000,2\n19:37:1 608,40000,4\n19:37:1 755,30000,4\n19:37:1 857,30000,2\n19:37:1 915,40000,6";
var margin = {
        top : 20,
        right : 90,
        bottom : 30,
        left : 50
    }, width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right, height = 500 - margin.top
            - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#svg").attr("width",
            width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height",
            height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr(
            "transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var buckets = d3.csv.parse(csv_data);

    buckets.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = new Date(timeFormat.parse(d.date));
        d.bucket = +d.bucket;
        d.count = +d.count;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) {
        return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) {
        return d.bucket;
    }));

    z.domain([ 0, d3.max(buckets, function(d) {
        return d.count;
    }) ]);
x.domain([ x.domain()[0], +x.domain()[1] + xStep ]);
    y.domain([ y.domain()[0], y.domain()[1] + yStep ]);

    // Display the tiles for each non-zero bucket.
    svg.selectAll(".tile").data(buckets).enter().append("rect").attr(
            "class", "tile").attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    }).attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.bucket + yStep);
    }).attr("width", x(xStep) - x(0)).attr("height", y(0) - y(yStep))
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return z(d.count);
            });

    // Add a legend for the color values.
    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend").data(
            z.ticks(6).slice(1).reverse()).enter().append("g").attr(
            "class", "legend").attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + (width + 20) + "," + (20 + i * 20) + ")";
    });

    legend.append("rect").attr("width", 20).attr("height", 20).style(
            "fill", z);

    legend.append("text").attr("x", 26).attr("y", 10).attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(String);

    svg.append("text").attr("class", "label").attr("x", width + 20).attr(
            "y", 10).attr("dy", ".35em").text("Count");

    // Add an x-axis with label.
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform",
            "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis).append("text").attr(
            "class", "label").attr("x", width).attr("y", -6).attr(
            "text-anchor", "end").text("Time");

    // Add a y-axis with label.
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).append("text")
            .attr("class", "label").attr("y", 6).attr("dy", ".71em").attr(
                    "text-anchor", "end").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .text("Latency");
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/jsx">
    ReactDOM.render(<svg id="svg"></svg>,document.getElementById('container'));     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But graph is not visible in the browser when I'm requesting to this page. what is that I'm missing here?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/generating-svg-with-react/)

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado- yeah right. corrected this mistake. In other way can I render this svg variable itself by selecting div or something like that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question... Do you mean if you can choose a div to render the SVG inside it?

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado- yeah like that. But I'm tried with that also but still not working for me.

Comment: Do you have anything in the page with an ID named "svg"? If not, just create a div with that ID, or simply select the "body".

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado- yes I'm created another svg element just for try with id is svg. I don't want to select body because I want to render using react.js

Answer (score 4):

Since the d3 code is executed before the React code, the svg element doesn't exist yet. You can create a react class which renders the svg element, and then place your d3 code `componentDidMount` and/or `componentDidUpdate` method. React renders everything in a shadow DOM before adding it to the actual DOM so you need to make sure the element is available before you can select it with d3 (or jQuery, etc.)

```
class MySVG extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    var svg = d3.select('#my-svg');
    //Do svg stuff
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg id="my-svg"></svg>
    );
  }

}

export default MySVG;
```

and then render `mySVG` with ReactDOM.render()

Comment: Note that this is using ES6 syntax. I am not completely sure how it would look in vanilla javascript..

Answer (score 2):

I published a tiny npm package to resolve this. `npm i hook-use-d3` and then use like so:

In sample below I added some d3 code to show you animated green dot, to make sure you will have visual to confirm it works. As an extra, it's also animated :)

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import React from "react";
import useD3 from "hook-use-d3";

export default function SomeComponent() {
  const d3ref = useD3((svg) => {
    const circle = svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 50)
      .attr("cy", 50)
      .attr("r", 1)
      .attr("fill", "#4CAF50");

    function animate() {
      let radius = 5;
      let distance = 35;
      circle
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("r", () => d3.interpolate(radius, radius + distance))
        .on("end", () => {
          radius = circle.attr("r");
          distance = 35;

          circle
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attrTween("r", () => d3.interpolate(radius, radius - distance))
            .on("end", animate);
        });
    }
    animate();
  }, []);

  return <svg ref={d3ref} style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}></svg>;
}
```

If you want to see the code of the hook, posted it on github: https://github.com/liesislukas/hook-use-d3/tree/main

[image]

Comment: If anyone is trying to get this working with TypeScript, I ported this fine example to TypeScript in https://gist.github.com/fasiha/d23ea4905cf5e4650e8cdeabdd15249f (and embedded your library hook into the body of the component to see exactly how it worked). There were some confusing type errors so hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Unless "svg" is the ID of an existing svg in the page, it seems to me that you forgot to append the SVG in your variable `svg`:

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg")
    .append("svg")//this appends the SVG
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height",  height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Comment: yeah right. corrected this mistake still facing same issue graph is not visible in rendered svg.